# Rails, heroku installing puma on different disk gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, puma

I created free account on heroku. Now I am trying this [getting started](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#introduction). My `DevKit` `Ruby` and `openssl` are placed inside my `D:\` disk, `not C:\`, beacuse there is reason why I can't use `C:\` disk. All files directories are placed in my path.

I have tried to install puma gem by this [method](https://github.com/hicknhack-software/rails-disco/wiki/Installing-puma-on-windows), only defference is that disk name is `D:\`.

When I run `gem install puma -- --with-opt-dir=D:\openssl` it throws me an long error:

```
D:\>gem install puma -- --with-opt-dir=D:\openssl
Building native extensions with: '--with-opt-dir=D:\openssl'
This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing puma:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

 D:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150406-5096-1vz5x1.rb extconf.rb -
-with-opt-dir=D:\openssl
 checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... no
 checking for BIO_read() in -llibeay32... no
 *** extconf.rb failed ***
 Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
 libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
 need configuration options.

 Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=D:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby
    --with-puma_http11-dir
    --without-puma_http11-dir
    --with-puma_http11-include
    --without-puma_http11-include=${puma_http11-dir}/include
    --with-puma_http11-lib
    --without-puma_http11-lib=${puma_http11-dir}/lib
    --with-cryptolib
    --without-cryptolib
    --with-libeay32lib
    --without-libeay32lib

 extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2
 .11.1 for inspection.
 Results logged to D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.1.0
 /puma-2.11.1/gem_make.out
```

**UPDATE**

I have copied my `libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll` inside of my `D:\openssl\bin` to `D:\Ruby21-x64\bin`. It said me that it already has these files, so I replaced them.

When I run `gem install puma -- --with-opt-dir=D:\openssl` it still throws me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution.

Heroku site in this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#introduction) gives OpenSSL **ONLY FOR x86**. If you have x64 you need to download it from [there](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyinstaller/0rcD9Jlerh4/discussion).

I hope in future Heroku will provide x64 ssl links in their tutorials.

Comment: There's the [OpenKnapsack Repository on Bintray](https://bintray.com/oneclick/OpenKnapsack/openssl/) that now holds a bit easier to manage and up to date `OpenSSL` builds.