# installing gem puma on windows error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, server, puma

My first step when trying to install the gem puma is to enter gem install puma --version 2.12.3 into my command prompt. Then this error appears. I don't know what to make of it.

```
C:\Users>gem install puma --version 2.12.3
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing puma:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150809-8352-14jkju1.rb extconf.rb
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... no
checking for BIO_read() in -llibeay32... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-puma_http11-dir
        --without-puma_http11-dir
        --with-puma_http11-include
        --without-puma_http11-include=${puma_http11-dir}/include
        --with-puma_http11-lib
        --without-puma_http11-lib=${puma_http11-dir}/lib
        --with-cryptolib
        --without-cryptolib
        --with-libeay32lib
        --without-libeay32lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2
.12.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0
/puma-2.12.3/gem_make.out
```

Once I receive this , I follow these instructions https://github.com/hicknhack-software/rails-disco/wiki/Installing-puma-on-windows

And I receive this error:

```
C:\Users>gem install puma -- --with-opt-      dir=c:\
openssl
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
        127: The specified procedure could not be found.   - C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/r
uby/2.2.0/x64-mingw32/openssl.so
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Side note: here is the mkmf.log

[mkmf.log](http://notepub.com/#buttons=hidden&name=freshlikeuser123)

Please Help! thanks!

Comment: seems like you don't have libcrypto installed on your system

Comment: did you try steps posted on following link ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30204784/installing-puma-on-windows-error

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found answer for your question. [Here the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29470930/rails-heroku-installing-puma-on-different-disk-gives-error)

You must download `OpenSSL` libraries. There are two types OpenSSL libraries, one for 32bit other for 64bit.

After you installed them run `gem install puma -- --with-opt-dir=D:\openssl`

`--with-opt-dir=D:\openssl` is folder direction where you have downloaded libs.

Some tutorials have links to openssl which is for 32bit computers. I realized this after several failures. Then I have downloaded 64 bit version.